# Magento2: How to add custom attributes into CustomerGroups

Tags: magento2, custom, custom-attributes, customer-group, extension-attributes

I've already added some custom attributes into order and customer, now, I'm trying to do the same with `CustomerGroups` and it's not working. I'm failling on the first step, the setup script:

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_group', 'custom_code', [
            'type' => 'varchar'
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I run `setup:upgrade` it shows that:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
Wrong entity ID
```

Why? I searched on module-customer and I found the model I want to attach the custom attributes: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Group.php` and it has the constant:

```
const ENTITY = 'customer_group';
```

So why it's failing?

What I'm missing?

EDIT:

After @Sohel Rana response, I'm trying this way, but it's harder than I expect. I did the following steps:

1. I added a column on `customer_group` table with `InstallSchema`.
2. Defined the plugin for intercept the get and save methods:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\GroupRepository">
    <plugin name="Gsp_CustomerCrm::GroupRepository" type="Gsp\CustomerCrm\Plugin\GroupRepository"/>
</type>
```

3. Created the plugin, based with another plugin I have of order:

```
class GroupRepository
{

    protected $groupExtension;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtension $groupExtension)
    {
        $this->groupExtension = $groupExtension;
    }

    public function afterGetById(\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\GroupRepository $groupRepository, $group)
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $group->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->groupExtension;
        }
        $value = $group->getData('gsp_code') ? $group->getData('gsp_code') : null;
        $extensionAttributes->setData('gsp_code', $value);
        $group->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $group;
    }
}
```

But when I call getById method it shows that error:

```
Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Group::getData()
```

I see that the Group object hasn't got getData method, getGspCode doesn't exists neither. so how I can retrieve my attribute?

The only way I see it's doing by a custom query. But I feel a bit messy this solution. Is there a proper way to get my attribute?

After that I tried to do the same with `afterSave` method, and I have the same problem.

I don't get what is going on. I created a `beforeSave` and `afterSave`

with this code:

```
var_dump($group->__toArray());
```

And this is the result:

```
array(4) {
  ["code"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["tax_class_id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["tax_class_name"]=>
  string(6) "string"
  ["extension_attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["gsp_code"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["code"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["tax_class_id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["tax_class_name"]=>
  string(15) "Retail Customer"
}
```

Why on beforeSave appears my attribute but on afterSave doesn't?

Seems that this should work without any plugin, just saving and retrieving by itself, but for some reason is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying wrong. In magento, no 'curtomer_group' entity type. Open **eav_entity_type** table, you can find following entity_type

```
1   customer
2   customer_address
3   catalog_category
4   catalog_product
5   order       
6   invoice 
7   creditmemo  
8   shipment
```

So you can create attribute for this type.

Comment: I understand I can't add a custom attribute into `customer_group` by this way. So how do I do it? I need to create customerGroups via API adding customAttributes. I've seen on the API doc, there are `extension_attributes` How can I add information there? I've already created the `extension_attributes.xml` and the POST call works setting my extension attributes, but it doesn't save it.

Comment: Customer group use simple flat table. So you can create/update/delete using API, or Repository. All are available under 'Customer' module.

Comment: I have an extension that does this on the `InstallData` script:
        `$this->quoteSetup->addAttribute('quote_address', 'payment_fee_amount', [
            'type'=>'decimal'
        ]);`

How is this possible if you say only can create attributes for this 8 entities? what happens with `quote_address`?

Answer (score 0):

I`ve tried to add as extension_attribute, but it looks I need to create aroundSave plugin for GroupRepositoryInterface. Original save() method only moves extension_attributes to target object, but didn`t move custom det data from beforeSave plugin.